# Deployed Nginx Ingress Controller but service with type LoadBalancer has external IP pending

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, k3s, ingress-controller

I have a k3s (light weighted k8s) cluster running on my Raspberry PI. So, I am not using any cloud hosted cluster but a bear metal one on my Raspberry PI.

I have deployed a application with this manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world
          image: bashofmann/rancher-demo:1.0.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 200m
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            name: web
            protocol: TCP
```

I also created a service to forward traffic to the application pod. Its manifest is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo-app-svc
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  ports:
  - name: web
    protocol: TCP
    port: 31113
    targetPort: 8080
```

Then, I created a Ingress for the routing rules:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ing
  namespace: myapp
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx 
  rules:
  - host: myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: demo-app-svc 
            port:
              number: 31113
```

I successfully deployed above application pod, service & Ingress to my k3s cluster.  Like the manifests indicate, they are under namespace `myapp`.

The next thing I would like to do is to deploy the **Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller** in order to have the clients outside the cluster be able to access the deployed application.

So, I deployed it by :

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.2/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

The above command successfully deployed **Ingress Controller** under namespace `ingress-nginx` along with other objects as shown below with command `k get all -n ingress-nginx`:
[image]

As you can see above, the `LoadBalancer` type `service` external IP is with value `<pending>`. So, client outside the cluster still can not access the application pod.

Why is that & what do I miss deploying the Nginx Ingress Controller on a bear metal machine? The goal is to have an external IP that can be used to access the application pod from outside cluster, how can I achieve that?

**===== Update =====**

Based on the answer below from @Dawid Kruk , I decided to use the k3s default Traefik Ingress Controller.

So, I deleted all the deployed Nginx Ingress Controller resources by `k delete all --all -n ingress-nginx` .

Then, I checked the Traefik Ingress related `LoadBalancer` type service:
[image]

The `external IP` of that Traefik service is exactly my Raspberry PI's IP address!

So, added this IP to `/etc/hosts` to map it to the hostname defined in my Ingress object:

```
192.168.10.203 myapp.com
```

I opened browser & use address http://myapp.com, with the routing rules defined in my `Ingress` object (see the manifest for my ingress above), I hoped I could see my deployed web application now. But get `404 Page Not Found`.  What am I missing now to access my deployed application?

**Another side question:** I noticed when I check the deployed `Ingress` object, its IP address is empty, I wonder am I supposed to see an IP address for this object or not when the Traefik Ingress Controller takes effect?
[image]

**Another issue:** Now, when I re-deploy my ingress manifest by `k apply -f ingress.yaml`, I get error:

```
Resource: "networking.k8s.io/v1, Resource=ingresses", GroupVersionKind: "networking.k8s.io/v1, Kind=Ingress"
...
for: "ingress.yaml": error when patching "ingress.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1/ingresses?timeout=10s": service "ingress-nginx-controller-admission" not found
```

It looks like even I decided to use Traefik Ingress Controller, I still need to instal Nginx Ingress Controller. I get confused now, anyone can explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not K3S expert but I think I found a piece of documentation that is addressing your issue.

Take a look:

> #### Service Load Balancer
>
> Any service load balancer (LB) can be used in your K3s cluster. By default, K3s provides a load balancer known as [ServiceLB](https://github.com/k3s-io/klipper-lb) (formerly Klipper Load Balancer) that uses available host ports.
>
> Upstream Kubernetes allows Services of type LoadBalancer to be created, but doesn't include a default load balancer implementation, so these services will remain `pending` until one is installed. Many hosted services require a cloud provider such as Amazon EC2 or Microsoft Azure to offer an external load balancer implementation. By contrast, the K3s ServiceLB makes it possible to use LoadBalancer Services without a cloud provider or any additional configuration.
>
> #### How the Service LB Works
>
> The ServiceLB controller watches Kubernetes [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) with the `spec.type` field set to `LoadBalancer`.
>
> For each LoadBalancer Service, a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) is created in the `kube-system` namespace. This DaemonSet in turn creates Pods with a `svc-` prefix, on each node. **These Pods use iptables to forward traffic from the Pod's NodePort, to the Service's ClusterIP address and port.**
>
> If the ServiceLB Pod runs on a node that has an external IP configured, the node's external IP is populated into the Service's `status.loadBalancer.ingress` address list. Otherwise, the node's internal IP is used.
>
> If multiple LoadBalancer Services are created, a separate DaemonSet is created for each Service.
>
> It is possible to expose multiple Services on the same node, as long as they use different ports.
>
> If you try to create a LoadBalancer Service that listens on port 80, the ServiceLB will try to find a free host in the cluster for port 80. If no host with that port is available, the LB will remain Pending.
>
> -- *[Docs.k3s.io: Networking](https://docs.k3s.io/networking#service-load-balancer)*

As a possible solution, I'd recommend to use `Traefik` as it's a default `Ingress` controller within `K3S`.

The `Pending` status on your `LoadBalancer` is most likely caused by another service used on that port (`Traefik`).

If you wish to still use `NGINX`, the same documentation page explains how you can disable `Traefik`.

---

#### UPDATE

I'd be more careful to delete resources as you did. The following command:

- `k delete all --all -n ingress-nginx`

Will not delete all of the resources created. The better way in my opinion would be to use the command that you've used to create and instead of:

- `kubectl create -f ...`

Use:

- `kubectl delete -f ...`

I assume that you did not modify your `Ingress` definition, hence you receive the error and the `kubectl get ingress` is showing incorrect results.

What you will need to do:

```yaml
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx # <-- DELETE IT OR CHANGE TO "traefik"
```

Either delete or change should work as `traefik` is set to be a default `IngressClass` for this setup.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please check my updated post above based on your answer?

Comment: @user842225 I reproduced your setup and updated the answer. Take a look.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I also figured out & exactly like you said.